# Parsing XML data into Android ListFragment

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-listfragment

I have successfully parsed XML into a ListActivity. I have successfully populated a ListFragment from an array. However, I cannot combine these two activities as there are no online tutorials.

*Can someone show me how to populate a ListFragment for Android 3.0+ and populate it with data from an online XML file using the Android SAX parser?*

I am much more interested, not in the parsing class, but in how to display it in conjunction with a ListFragment.  To keep it simple, lets say I use a SimpleAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ covers this issue. It's not clear enough, it throws too many different way to do the job at you, but it does describe everything completely, and it works.